# Improving high IOps Folder (Tomcat and Vmware)

Tags: vmware-esxi, tomcat, iops, ramdisk

Good day.

We're moving a Tomcat from a physical server to one virtual Server. In the physical, and because the high IOps for the temp folder (¡developers!) we bought a Ramdisk software.

My question is... Will a ramdisk software work in a vmware virtual machine? Is there better options? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will a ramdisk software work in a vmware virtual machine?

Yes, of course.

> Is there better options?

If you can live with the volatility then no, RAM's pretty damn fast, even in a VM - if you need nonvolatility then look at something like NVMe-based storage.